# How to check if a user is logged in when using auth-method FORM

Tags: java, tomcat, j-security-check

I am using auth-method FORM with apache tomcat to authenticate users. I am using the default j_security_check action.

If a user has signed in, I must display a Sign out link. Else a sign in link. How do I check if the user has signed in?

Also, how do I log a user out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()` and check it to find the logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

The state of being logged in is identical to the condition that `HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()` returns non-null.

Comment: There is no `getUserPrincipal()` method in `HttpServlet`, it is in `HttpServletRequest` as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(request.authenticate(response)){
    System.out.println("The User is Authenticated");
}else{
   System.out.println("The User is not Authenticated");
}
```

Use this code inside your JSP or in the Servlets.